# AWS EB Flask app deployment could not get HTTP header authorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, http-headers, authorization, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a Flask app to AWS EB. It's an API that uses HTTP header auth as `Authorization: {token}`. The problem is that the app can not access to them when I make a request.

The code works perfectly on local and deployed on a VPS. I read some other similar questions but their solutions do not work.

My `.ebextensions/01_flask.config` file looks like this:

```
container_commands:
  01_wsgipass:
    command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'

option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/app:$PYTHONPATH"
    "ALLOWED_HOSTS": ".elasticbeanstalk.com"

  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: application.py
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
```

I deployed a Django application in AWS EB a few days ago and had the same problem. But in that situation, the `01_wsgipass` command from the config file worked out perfectly. 
I don't understand why it does not work in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

1) .ebextensions/01_flask.config

```
container_commands:
03wsgipass:
command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```

2) endpoint set decorator

```
@cross_origin(origin=CORS_ORIGINS, headers=['Authorization'])
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Comment: I actually solved it, but don't remeber how. Thanks for the answer, I'll check it for my next deployment.